# Silverlight Animation: Cannot resolve TargetName

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation, silverlight-4.0, storyboard

I'm having issues with animations. First I tried animating using the `VisualStateManager` from within the XAML mark-up. That worked when trying to animate the `Opacity` property, but not the `Height` property. Then I thought I'd give it a try by animating programmatically so I could debug more easily. Accordingly, I kept getting the following:

> Cannot resolve TargetName ExplorerBody

I donno why animating the opacity works but not the height, and I do not know why it cannot resolve the TargetName. Checkout my code, maybe you can see something that I couldn't:

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Controls:ApplicationExplorer">                        
        <Border BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness}" 
                CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CornerRadius}" 
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}" 
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}" >

            <Grid x:Name="Root" MinWidth="100">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HeaderBackgroundBrush}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TitleStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Controls:LayoutToggleButton Grid.Column="2" x:Name="LayoutButton" Cursor="Hand" />
                </Grid>
                <Border x:Name="ExplorerBody" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" 
                        Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" >
                    <toolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget AllowedSourceEffects="Copy" x:Name="treeViewDropTarget" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <sdk:TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Nodes}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                            ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TreeItemTemplate}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                    </toolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="LayoutGroup">
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Minimized">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ExplorerBody" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="1"  To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </vsm:VisualState>
                    <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Maximized" />
                </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
            </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And here's how I tried to get it done using C# code:

```
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, _explorerBody.Name);
    storyboard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
    DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
    anim.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500));
    anim.To = 0;
    storyboard.Children.Add(anim);
    storyboard.Begin();
```

So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got it to work... The following link was helpful:

http://mindfusion.eu/Forum/YaBB.pl?board=diaglite_disc;action=display;num=1278055916

Here's my code in case someone needs it:

```
    private void SwitchLayoutState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_currentState == ControlLayout.None)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Control layout cannot be None.");
        }

        Duration duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400));
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, _explorerBody);

        if (_currentState == ControlLayout.Maximized)
        {
            animation.To = 0;

            storyboard.Completed += (s, args) => { _explorerBody.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; };
            storyboard.Begin();

            _currentState = ControlLayout.Minimized;
            _layoutButton.Content = "+";
        }
        else if (_currentState == ControlLayout.Minimized)
        {
            _explorerBody.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            animation.To = 1;
            storyboard.Begin();

            _currentState = ControlLayout.Maximized;
            _layoutButton.Content = "-";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original attempt matches the MS documentation -

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

storyboard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, _explorerBody.Name);

storyboard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
```

and your solution -

```
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, _explorerBody);
```

In particular replacing the -

```
  storyboard.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty part with -
  Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, _explorerBody);
```

is what cracks it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the TargetName error, but I'm pretty sure you need to have something like 
(UIElement.Height) for the TargetProperty.
Can't try to reproduce your issue now, so just a wild guess...

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ExplorerBody" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Height)" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="1"  To="0" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. I actually prefer to make it work in the code rather than the XAML because animating the `Opacity` (which works fine in XAML) looks better, but in this case I need to handler the `Completed` event and I prefer to handle it inside the class of my custom control (not on the view model). Accordingly, do you have any idea why I'm getting that error?

Comment: well, nothing prevents you from handling the completed event in your control, even if the storyboard and its triggers are defined in xaml.
You could also set the visibility to Collapsed and change the content property of the button at the end of your animation, using a DoubleAnimationUsingKeyframe.
The best solution in that case is to leverage States and make your storyboard go from one state to another.
Writing the storyboard all in code becomes hairy as soon as your animation get more complex.